# What is required to register .com.au domains?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I have a website that allows people to search for instructors. It's currently working in the USA and UK.

I'm wanting to start marketing the website to the Australian market, and so have been looking at registering a .com.au domain name.

What is the best way about doin this as it doesn't seem particularly simple? Apparently I need an ABN or an Australian company but as I'm not an Australian citizen this presumably would be impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a good blog post](http://www.coopermills.com.au/wordpress/index.php/2011/11/registration-of-au-domains-by-foreigners/) about registering .co.au domains as a foreigner, the law firm which posted it links to [this page on their site](http://www.coopermills.com.au/domain-name-lawyers-udrp-audrp.php) going over how to register a domain

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.domainregistration.com.au/domains/tips/):

> To be eligible for a com.au or net.au domain name, registrants must
>   be:
>   -an Australian registered company; or
>   -trading under a registered business name in any Australian State or Territory; or
>   -an Australian partnership or sole trader; or
>   -a foreign company licensed to trade in Australia; or
>   -an owner of an Australian Registered Trade Mark; or
>   -an applicant for an Australian Registered Trade Mark 1 ; or
>   -an association incorporated in any Australian State or Territory; or
>   -an Australian commercial statutory body.

That was easy to find with a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20register%20a%20.com.au?).

Comment: Thanks, although I already read that and was more after any experience from people who aren't in Australia owning a .com.au, whether they registered a business, registered as sole trader etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice now to get a domain registrar that can register a trademark for you. They also offer Trustee Services that allow you to purchase domain names through their local contacts. There's no need to have your own local address/business. Registrars today can do that for you for an additional fee over the domain registration price.